# Able to malloc more than docker-compose mem_limit

Tags: docker, malloc, docker-compose, cgroups

I'm trying to limit my container so that it doesn't take up all the RAM on the host. From [the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory) I understand that `--memory` limits the RAM and `--memory-swap` limits (RAM+swap). From [the docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources) it looks like the terms for those are `mem_limit` and `memswap_limit`, so I've constructed the following docker-compose file:

```
> cat docker-compose.yml
version: "2"

services:
    stress:
        image: progrium/stress
        command: '-m 1 --vm-bytes 15G --vm-hang 0 --timeout 10s'

        mem_limit: 1g
        memswap_limit: 2g
```

The [progrium/stress image](https://hub.docker.com/r/progrium/stress/) just runs `stress`, which in this case spawns a single thread which requests 15GB RAM and holds on to it for 10 seconds.

I'd expect this to crash, since 15>2. (It does crash if I ask for more RAM than the host has.)

The kernel has cgroups enabled, and `docker stats` shows that the limit is being recognised:

```
> docker stats
CONTAINER       CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %       NET I/O       BLOCK I/O       PIDS
7624a9605c70    0.00%     1024MiB / 1GiB        99.99%      396B / 0B     172kB / 0B      2
```

So what's going on? How do I actually limit the container?

**Update:**
Watching `free`, it looks like the RAM usage is effectively limited (only 1GB of RAM is used) but the swap is not: the container will gradually increase swap usage until it's eaten though all of the swap and `stress` crashes (it takes about 20secs to get through 5GB of swap on my machine).

**Update 2:**
Setting `mem_swappiness: 0` causes an immediate crash when requesting more memory than `mem_limit`, regardless of `memswap_limit`.

Answer (score 0):

Running `docker info` shows `WARNING: No swap limit support`

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#your-kernel-does-not-support-cgroup-swap-limit-capabilities this is disabled by default ("Memory and swap accounting incur an overhead of about 1% of the total available memory and a 10% overall performance degradation.") You can enable it by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file:

Add or edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line to add the following two key-value pairs:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"`
then update GRUB with `update-grub` and reboot.